# Creation of a sum Loop from the bottom down - VBA - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hello Stack overflow community and thanks in advance for all the help you could give me.

I am currently trying to create a loop to go through a column and create a sum of the data that is below that till the next blank line and in the next blank line create a new sum again doing the same process till that we get to two blanks following each other.

The below code does something similar but in the sum is upward and not downward.
Would anybody have a solution? Thanks a million for your help.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim offset_rows As Long

Set cell = Range("O2")

Do While Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(1, 0))
    offset_rows = Range(cell, cell.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1
    Set cell = cell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    'cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & offset_rows & "]C:R[-1]C)"
    cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & offset_rows & "]C:R[1]C)"
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly tweaked the macro and it does now the sum downward.
Thanks again so much for your help, really appreciate it!

```
    Sub SumRowsAbove()
```

Dim StartRow        As Long
Dim SumRow          As Long
Dim lRow            As Long
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim BlankRowsCtr    As Integer
Dim FormulaRow      As Integer

' modify to your sheet name
With Sheets("Macroprep")

```
' find last row with data in column "O"
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
StartRow = 3
BlankRowsCtr = 0

For lRow = 2 To LastRow + 1
    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(lRow, "O")) Then
        SumRow = lRow
        BlankRowsCtr = 0
    Else
        BlankRowsCtr = BlankRowsCtr + 1

        ' if 2 or more rows are empty >> exit sub
        If BlankRowsCtr >= 2 Then Exit Sub

        FormulaRow = StartRow - 1
        .Cells(FormulaRow, "O").Formula = "=SUM(O" & StartRow & ":O" & SumRow & ")"
        StartRow = lRow + 1
    End If

Next lRow
```

End With

End Sub

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the variable have not been taken in account in my post - not sure how to edit - I still hope it will be useful to the coommunity - thanks again Shai!